# Spring-boot ErrorPage not working with standalone Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am still struggling to get the Spring-boot error page stuff working completely in a standalone tomcat with deployed WAR file.

I have a configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [ GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, SecurityAutoConfiguration, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, JmxAutoConfiguration ] )
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application ) {
        application.sources( Application )
    }
```

and also have my error handling configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
class ErrorConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override public void customize( ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container ) {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/errors/404" ))
    }
```

This info seems to be getting used, but not as I would expect - If I just go to a non-existent URL then I get the tomcat default 404 page - however, Spring does seem to be returning my ErrorPage path, as the Tomcat page looks like this:

```
HTTP Status 404 - //errors/404

type Status report

message //errors/404

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
```

If I change my error config and use a different path, then that path gets passed through as the 404 message - Does anyone know what I have missed? I am expecting the message to just be something like "Not found" and the path /errors/404 to be used to resolve a view/controller to render the error page.

---

**UPDATE**
I have the error path mapped as a standard view controller in my web config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Register static views that dont need controller calls - map URLs direct to views
     */
    @Override public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/errors/404").setViewName("errors/404")
        registry.addViewController("/errors/500").setViewName("errors/500")
    }
```

Also, if I just go straight to the error path in the browser - /errors/404 - then I get the error page I expect.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have created a dummy Spring Boot web app with auto-error handling and deployed to my tomcat running in Eclipse and the whitelabel error page displays correctly. I then deploy it on to my development server tomcat and the whitelabel error pages stop working (I see default tomcat 404 page).

My web.xml is the same across both (copied the web.xml from eclipse to dev server) and the server.xml is below (essentially the same as the eclipse version really)

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Custom">
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPoolwr" minSpareThreads="4" maxThreads="500" namePrefix="catalina-execwr-"></Executor>
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" executor="tomcatThreadPoolwr" maxThreads="10"></Connector>
    <Connector port="9998" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8445" maxThreads="500" tomcatAuthentication="false" connectionTimeout="21000"></Connector>
    <Engine jvmRoute="custom" name="Custom" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"></Realm>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true"  unpackWARs="false" appBase="/tmp/dev/custom" workDir="/tmp/dev/custom/work" createDirs="true">
        <Context docBase="/tmp/dev/ROOT" path="/" reloadable="true" override="true"/>
        <Valve pattern="common" directory="/var/log/tmp" prefix="custom_access_log." className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" suffix=".log" resolveHosts="false"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Furthermore:

1. If i navigate directly to /error I see the whitelabel page, so the endpoint is working correctly
2. If I create a file called "error" in the webroot, this gets picked up and displayed. So it seems like the application is trying to re-route my 404 correctly, but for some reason is only looking for "error" file, rather than the "error" endpoint in the application

---

**UPDATE 3**

I have investigated further, and even if I use the exact same server.xml and web.xml on a local, clean tomcat install it still works locally.

I have also seen that it appears to be a problem with the RequestDispatch for the request.

If I run the following code on my development server (anywhere, but from a controller for example) it doesn't work:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/errors/404").forward(request,response);
```

But the following does:

```
servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/errors/404").forward(request,response);
```

(where request and response are HttpServletRequest/Response and servletContext is an autowired ServletContext object)

Both of the above example work correctly on a clean local tomcat install - any ideas what might cause problems for the request linked RequestDispatcher whilst the ServletContext RequestDispatcher still works?  The ErrorPageFilter uses the request linked RequestDispatcher so hits this problem.

Comment: Where did you define the handler for "/errors/404"?

Comment: Its defined as a view controller in my web config- just mapping to src/main/resources/templates/errors/404.HTML (im using thymeleaf, but that's just static HTML file)

Comment: Can you post that code? It seesm like it's the viewhandler that it can't find.

Comment: Thanks @DaveSyer - have updated with the config.  I have tried including/excluding the Boot error config and neither seems to make a difference to this behaviour - is there any other error config I am missing?

Comment: Isn't it the "//" (double slash) that's broken (Tomcat can't resolve it, and doesn't bother to try and normalize the path). I guess you need to register it without the leading "/" in the container?

Comment: Wait, didn't you say this was in a standalone Tomcat? There is no point registering an error page for the embedded container in that case is there?

Comment: @DaveSyer I have tried removing the leading slash but still no joy - the message with the 404 becomes relative to the current URL you are on and still just the default tomcat 404 page

Comment: @DaveSyer This is what I originally would have guessed, but from the docs/comments in the source code, I was understanding that the ErrorPageFilter basically made this supported in standalone deployments? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/ErrorPageFilter.java

Comment: Ah, yes, that rings a bell. So it should be working. Can you create a test project and post a link on Github?

Comment: Sure thing, will try and re-create it.

Comment: @DaveSyer I created a basic Spring boot starter project and deployed it to my tomcat instance, and that had the same problem just trying to load the default whitelabel page. I then deployed it to a fresh tomcat on my local machine and that worked ok - so looks like some config in my tomcat config that is affecting it - any ideas what might be?  web.xml more or less looks the same across the two - the server.xml is a bit more complicated as it has specific service/connectors defined for the app - that likely to cause issues you think?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I couldn't say without looking at the `server.xml`. Does it set a default `web.xml`?

Comment: @DaveSyer it has a server level web.xml (I havent added an application specific web.xml) - but looking through it, except for some MIME mappings there isnt any difference between that web.xml and the web.xml I have on my local tomcat running (where it is working)

Comment: So can we see the server.xml?

Comment: @DaveSyer still no joy - I have now added some details on the setup using the dummy Spring Boot app. I have also included the server.xml configuration.  The error handling just doesn't seem to be routing to application/controller endpoints

Comment: Different version of Tomcat?

Comment: @DaveSyer 7.0.54 and 7.0.47 - will try using the same version of tomcat, but only minor differences, so assume that should be ok?

Comment: @DaveSyer tried both on 7.0.54 - results both as in original scenario.

Comment: @DaveSyer - added another update :) Looks like the request linked RequestDispatcher is not mapping it ok. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was caused because there was a ROOT directory being created in the tomcat appBase (this was being created as part of the WAR deploy process) - and it looks like that then caused some confusion with two ROOT contexts (the WAR was deployed as a ROOT war).

Fixing the tomcat setup so it just had the WAR file as expected this started to work.